# How in twig to set 2 dimentional array in macros

Tags: twig

How in twig to set 2 dimentional array in macros and to run it?
I did :

```
 {{ components.menu_item( "Hostels", 'hostel', {'admin/hostel/index': 'All Hostels'}, {'admin/hostel/active_featured_listings': 'Active Featured Hostels'} )  }}

{% macro menu_item(title, active_admin_link, items_array) %}
    title::{{ title }}<br>
    items_array::{{ dump(items_array) }}<br>
{% endmacro %}  {# menu_item END #}
```

But only 1st array elemented was outputted

```
array (size=1) 'admin/hostel/index' => string 'All Hostels' (length=11)
```

What is rigth way and how make for circle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the Twig [doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#literals):

> ["foo", "bar"]: Arrays are defined by a sequence of expressions
>   separated by a comma (,) and wrapped with squared brackets ([]).

So try surround the input with squared brackets, as follow:

```
 {{ components.menu_item( "Hostels", 'hostel', [{'admin/hostel/index': 'All Hostels'}, {'admin/hostel/active_featured_listings': 'Active Featured Hostels'}] )  }}
```

Hope this help